# computational complexity of rational parametrisation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\cal C$ be a space curve defined as the common zeros of $n-1$ polynomials. Assuming that $\cal C$ admits a rational parametrisation, there is an algorithm generating a point on the curve through algebraic operations, given a value $\tau$ on the base field. This mapping covers all the curve apart from a finite number of points. The input of the algorithm is given by the polynomials defining $\cal C$ and the parameter $\tau$. Let me also assume that one point of $\cal C$ is known.

What is the minimal number of required algebraic operations in terms of $n$ and the degree of the polynomials? Let me assume that this number does not depend on $\tau$.

Comment: How do you encode the problem? It isn't clear from your question what the input and output should be, since you assume a rational parametrization exists, but not that it is necessarily known. Also, you assume the curve is a complete intersection --- is that necessary for you?

Comment: Thanks, for the comment. I modified the question accordingly. Yes, I am mainly interested in complete intersections.